# Combinatorial Argument for $i{n \choose i} = n {n-1 \choose i-1}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I ran across the identity $$i{n \choose i} = n {n-1 \choose i-1}$$ which can be easily proved using the definition ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}$ and a little bit of algebra. I was wondering if there was a simple combinatorial argument  to explain this identity. I'm not necessarily looking for a proof, but rather the heuristics behind why it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In how many ways can I choose $i$ people from $n$ to form a committee, then choose a chair? That's the left-hand side. What if I choose the chair first, then the rest of the committee? That's the right-hand side.